# Angular6: Input binding on custom component doesn't update correctly

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, angular6

First question ever on StackOverflow, how exciting!

Currently I have two custom components, both accepting a couple of input variables :

```html
<sod-matrix-table #matrix 
  [entities]="entities" 
  [pairs]="pairs" 
  [displayedColumns]="displayedColumns">
</sod-matrix-table>
```

and :

```html
<data-table 
  #table 
  [type]="sodMatrixQuery.targetType" 
  [query]="sodMatrixQuery" >
</data-table>
```

When updating the `entities`, `pairs` or `columns` of the first tag, everything updates correctly. For example, when I update the `displayedColumns` array in a component that uses the matrix table tag, the table inside of that component gets updated with the desired columns.
However, when I update the `sodMatrixQuery` in the component, and press the search button, the `query` object of the `data-table` isn't updated correctly, although they are bound together.

Example:

`data-table` has a field `query` and uses this query to send REST requests to the server. `SODMatrixComponent` has a field `sodMatrixQuery` and uses the tag of the `data-table`, binding his field to the other field.

An SOD Matrix contains pairs of objects. When I select 2 pairs, and press the search button, the `data-table` sends the REST request with 2 pairs. However, when I remove the two pairs, and press search again, the `data-table` component sends another REST request, again with 2 pairs instead of none. When pressing the search button a second time, the correct request is send.

I debugged and internally everything with the pairs goes fine, it's only the databinding that doesn't get updated in time. Any thoughts about this?

EDIT: This is the code that happens on the button click:

```
public search() {
    const tempQuery = new SODMatrixQuery(this.lhsType, this.rhsType, [], this.entities);

    // Only look at elements above the diagonal
    for (let i = 1; i < this.pairs.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
            const p = this.pairs[i][j];
            if (p.checked) {
                tempQuery.addToxicPair(p);
            }
        }
    }

    if (this.dataTable) {
        this.sodMatrixQuery = tempQuery;
        // this.dataTable.query = tempQuery;
        this.dataTable.loadDataPage();
    }

}
```

SODMatrixComponent variables :

```
@ViewChild("table")
public dataTable: ElimityDataTableComponent;

public sodMatrixQuery: SODMatrixQuery;
```

Datatable component :

```
@Input()
public query: Query;
```

SODMatrixQuery extends Query!

The commented line below is a fix, to update the query object directly, but I'm just curious why the databinding doesn't work.

Comment: What is the change detection strategy of your components? Have you checked this out yet: https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4 ?

Comment: How are you updating the `sodMatrixQuery`?

Comment: @AgashThamo. I haven't really set a particular strategy, so I guess it's the default? I just find it weird it works with one tag, and not with the other

Comment: @rinukkusu Updating my post now with more code!

Comment: Should be the default if you are not extending anything. If one of the `@Input`s is an object or an array, Angular will not detect changes if you change values within the object or the array, since it will compare the references, which will stay the same.
Edit: Is it possible for you to create a basic stackblitz and recreate your problem?

Comment: @AgashThamo. Currently at work, edited my post with some more code, which is all I can do for now

Comment: Looks like change detection would need a moment to breathe there - the databinding can't be updated between the setting of the `sodMatrixQuery` member and the `this.dataTable.loadDataPage()` call - that's why it still has the old value on the first call. After that change detection will be run and on the second call it will have the right values.

Comment: Ok sure, no worries. Are you listening to `ngOnChanges` and update your datatable then?

Comment: @AgashThamo. In the <sod-matrix-table> I don't use it, and the values update just fine. So I assumed it wasn't necessary in the sod-matrix-component

Comment: It depends on how your components are rendered, without seeing your full code I cannot come up with another suggestion. See @rinukkusu answer, I mostly do updates in custom components ike this.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like change detection would need a moment to breathe there - the databinding can't be updated between the setting of the `sodMatrixQuery` member and the `this.dataTable.loadDataPage()` call - that's why it still has the old value on the first call. After that change detection will be run and on the second call it will have the right values.

```
if (this.dataTable) {
    this.sodMatrixQuery = tempQuery;
    // can't update the bindings here
    this.dataTable.loadDataPage();
}
```

So looking at your current architecture, it would be better to move the `loadDataPage()` call to the dataTable component into the `OnChanges` lifecycle hook, like Agash said in the comments.

```
export class ElimityDataTableComponent implements OnChanges {
  // ...
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes.query) {
      this.loadDataPage();
    }
  }
```

This way, every time you update the `sodMatrixQuery`, it automatically loads the new data.